# Are missing/broken dependencies on OpenSUSE normal?

Tags: opensuse, software-rec, dependencies

I am re-installing our little LAMP server at work; I'm a bit tired of Ubuntu server, so I had a look around and decided on OpenSUSE: nicely supported, well maintained, blah blah however -- pretty much every package I try to install seems to have missing dependencies. I'm trying to get apache2 and it's various modules like PHP and docs and etc installed, but I'm constantly hitting missing dependencies using both YaST and zypper. I am well aware of how to resolve them, but in truth I shouldn't have to and I just can't be bothered. Perhaps I'm a terrible human being but is this a result of bad install/config somewhere or is this normal for OpenSUSE?

In terms of repos *zypper lr -d* tells me that all the standard repos (non-oss, repo-oss, update, update-non-oss) are all enabled; only the source and debug repos are disabled. Never used OpenSuse before, so I am likely missing something here. Any pointers on getting repos that actually work/have better dependencies?

------------------------ Edit 1 --------------------------------

```
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
Resolving package dependencies...

Problem: apache2-mod_php5-5.4.20-12.1.x86_64 requires php5 = 5.4.20, but this requirement cannot be provided
  uninstallable providers: php5-5.4.20-1.2.x86_64[openSUSE-13.1-1.10]
                   php5-5.4.20-1.2.i586[repo-oss]
                   php5-5.4.20-1.2.x86_64[repo-oss]
                   php5-5.4.20-12.1.i586[repo-update]
                   php5-5.4.20-4.1.i586[repo-update]
                   php5-5.4.20-8.2.i586[repo-update]
                   php5-5.4.20-12.1.x86_64[repo-update]
                   php5-5.4.20-4.1.x86_64[repo-update]
                   php5-5.4.20-8.2.x86_64[repo-update]
 Solution 1: deinstallation of patterns-openSUSE-minimal_base-conflicts-13.1-13.6.1.x86_64
 Solution 2: do not install apache2-mod_php5-5.4.20-12.1.x86_64
 Solution 3: do not install apache2-mod_php5-5.4.20-12.1.x86_64
 Solution 4: break apache2-mod_php5-5.4.20-12.1.x86_64 by ignoring some of its dependencies

Choose from above solutions by number or cancel [1/2/3/4/c] (c):
```

Repeat for *zypper in php5* except it needs *smtp_daemon* which then gives a conflict with an existing mail daemon installed with the base OS. Can't remember the last time I had to deal with dependency issues!

---

Comment: No, this is not normal. Could you post the actual output from e.g. `zypper in apache2`?

Comment: Cheers, see original post edits, too long for a comment (I'm a stack exchange noob, if there's a better way to add info do let me know)

Comment: Editing your questing to add requested information is fine. See below for my answer.

Answer (score 6):

*Patterns* are a way to install a set of packages that belong to a common theme (everything needed for a web server, say). The machine at hand has been installed with a *minimal* pattern. This includes a lot of conflicts to prevent superfluous packages that are *recommended* (but to *required*) by the packages you actually want from being installed.

You can resolve the conflict by removing the offending pattern (choose solution number 1). Removing the pattern does not remove the packages that belong to the pattern, but (as always) be sure to review the list of changes zypper prints before answering "y".

Comment: Ah ok, that explains the issue! I am wondering if it is now worth re-installing the server with just the base install, I'm not keen to just remove the pattern and leave the software since if something doesn't work I then have several potentially conflicting packages to work through to find the error... Cheers for the answer!

Comment: I wouldn't re-install. A pattern is merely a set of constraints (i.e. requirements and conflicts), so removing it does not change the system. Moreover, nothing should be broken right now (unless you selected a solution _break xxx…_ when installing software at some point.